# Copy string source into destination, and then append a character in C

Tags: c, string, function, loops, pointers

Copy string into destination, append a character C at the end of destination, then null terminate destination. We can assume sizeof(destination) >= strlen(source) + 2

```
void strcpyALT(char* dest, char* source, char c)  {
  char* dst = dest;
  char* src = source;
  while(*src) {
      *(dst++) = *(src++);
  }
  dst = dst + 1;
  *dst = c;
  dst = dst + 1;
  *dst = '\0';
}
```

I am new to C, but two questions, does this code seem correct given the assumption? I setup some local tests for myself, but just want to be sure I didnt make any glaring errors I am not catching. Also, is there a cleaner way to write the last 4 lines?

Comment: Why are you not using `strcpy` for copy?

Comment: "I setup some local tests for myself" - so, does it work? If it does, what are you actually asking here??

Comment: first `dst = dst + 1;` make gap.

Comment: Replace: `dst = dst + 1;
  *dst = c;
  dst = dst + 1;
  *dst = '\0';` with `*dst++ = c; *dst = '\0';`.  Consider the merits of `return dst;` and changing the function signature to return a `char *`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `return dest;` ?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: No — `return dst;`, returning a pointer to the end of the created string.  You already know the beginning; knowing where the end is makes subsequent concatenation operations simpler.  If I were redesigning the standard library functions, they'd return the end pointer, not the start.  The 'nested call' benefit isn't a major benefit (IMO).  Not knowing where the end of the result is can be a 'major' cost (at least, a cost — you have to run `strlen()` when the called function could save you that cost).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I got you.

Comment: @RohanKumar: One reason for not using `strcpy()` is that you'd have to rescan the string to find the end in order to concatenate the extra character.  This way, you don't have to rescan the string.

Answer (score 2):

> does this code seem correct given the assumption?

No.

```
  while(*src) {
      *(dst++) = *(src++);
  }
  dst = dst + 1;
  *dst = c;
```

Here, when you exit the loop, `dst` will already point to the location that `c` should be writen (appended to string). When you do `dst = dst + 1;`, you leave that location untouched, and write `c` to the next position than the desired one.

So discard `dst = dst + 1;`

(Stretch) Test it more if in doubt.

> Also, is there a cleaner way to write the last 4 lines?

There are other ways (to write the 3 lines now), but this is clean enough, I would say.

Answer (score 0):

In Short : Remove this line, one just after loop,
 "  dst = dst + 1 ".   Rest all ok.

> is there a cleaner way to write the last 4 lines?

```
*dest++ = c;   
*dest   = '\0';    //reduced to 2 lines.
```